# How to aggregate on multiple columns using SQL or spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have following table:

```
Id col1 col2
1  a    1   
1  b    2   
1  c    3   
2  a    1   
2  e    3   
2  f    4
```

Expected output is:

```
Id col3
1  a1b2c3
2  a1e3f4
```

The aggregation computation involves 2 columns, is this supported in SQL?

Comment: I think aggregation can only aggregate on one column, so I need to combine 2 columns for from a new column then aggregation on that new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark SQL you can do it like this:

```sql
SELECT Id, aggregate(list, '', (acc, x) -> concat(acc, x)) col3
FROM (SELECT Id, array_sort(collect_list(concat(col1, col2))) list
      FROM df
      GROUP BY Id )
```

or in one select:

```sql
SELECT Id, aggregate(array_sort(collect_list(concat(col1, col2))), '', (acc, x) -> concat(acc, x)) col3
FROM df
GROUP BY Id
```

Higher-order [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) function is used in this example.

> aggregate(expr, start, merge, finish) - Applies a binary operator to an initial state and all elements in the array, and reduces this to a single state. The final state is converted into the final result by applying a finish function.